# Fat arrow function and how a fat arrow function works

Tags: javascript

I saw this question in a quiz, how is a fat arrowed question works? is there any difference in the following code, if if yes why, if no why?:

```
    var abc = function() {
        return {
          log : function() {
            console.log(this.val);
          }
        };
    }

    var def = function(){
        return{
          log : () => {
            console.log(this.val);
          }
        };
    }
```

Comment: no significant difference in this simple code

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

A fat arrow function automatically binds to `this`.  It help avoid code where you have to save `this` in some other variable like `that`... such as in deeply nested callback hell. It is also more terse.